# php friend request system not sending correct data from submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and sql. I created a table for friend request notifications. The names are pulled from the table of requests. The notifications are displayed on the  [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Yg2.png) using a while loop. Each request shows the persons name who made the request, and has the level of friendship the user will make. Each notification has its own submit button.  When I click any of the submit buttons it takes the information from the last notification on the page. How I can get the correct information to post when a given submit button is pressed.

```
echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
echo '<div class="container-sm posts shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">';
echo '<div class="container title"><h3>'; echo $current_user; echo '</h3></div>';
echo '<div class="container content">';


if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if( $current_user == $row["currentUser"]){
      if($row["current_request"] == 1){
        $_SESSION["fid"] = $row["friend_request_name"];
          echo '<form action = "include/approve_friend_request.php" method = "POST">';
            echo $row["friend_request_name"];echo '<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="d" name="friend_reqest_level">';
            
            echo '<option value="1">friends</option>';
            echo '<option value="2">best friends</option>';
            echo ' </select>';
            echo '<button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submt</button> ';
            echo '<br>';
          }
    }         
  }
}

echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="container footer"><p class="footer">.</p></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Your opening `form` tag does not appear to have a closing counterpart. Which means you are effectively "nesting" form elements, which is not allowed to begin with in HTML. So the browser will render this as _one_ big form. And since all the select fields have the same name, you only get the value of the last one.

Comment: And beside the closing `</form>` you somehow have to send the id of the friend request along with the selected option. Otherwise how would you know which button is pressed? And note `$_SESSION["fid"]` is overwritten for every row you process.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. Since there is a while loop the fid gets overwritten. Is there a different way that would allow me to send the id from the specific form/ submission combination? Is there a different way I can display the information that would allow me to get the submission from a specific row?